# Hidden Folder not showing in Finder with show all hidden files

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I have a FreeBSD server where I store my web files. One of the files I have been using for years has the naming convention `._Folder`

[image: Finder before Go To Folder Dialog]

When I try to open this file in the Finder it doesn't even show, even with the following preference activated:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

When I go to `Go > Go to Folder >`

Then type `/Volumes/web/website/public_html/._Folder`

In the background I can see that the Finder updates to show the hidden folder. If I hit `cancel` on this dialog without hitting `enter` I can see the folder.

[image: Finder showing the hidden folder]

But when I turn down the triangle, it disappears.

When I have the `Go to Folder` dialog open and press `enter` the Finder shows the contents of the folder for about 2 seconds before it dumps me into a duplicated version of the `public_html` parent folder with a path of `/Volumes/web/website/public_html/public_html`. This folder at this path does not exist, but the Finder shows it.

If I try to access the folder again, I get the following message:
[image: Screenshot from Finder]

I've checked the permissions on the folders to make sure that's not the issue. I can edit the files and the folder on a Windows machine as well, and on the FreeBSD machine from the command line, but would really love to use some of the apps on my Mac.

The `._` naming convention is this way to match what is on the production server on the web.

All of the hidden files and folders with a single `.` character in front only are working. Anything with a `._` isn't showing at all.

I'm running 10.8.5 on a 3.33gHz 6 Core Xeon.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Finder is out...

> > Mac OS X does not show you companion files unless you use Terminal, and sometimes not even then.  (It shows *invisible* files rather easily, but to Mac OS X, both "MyFile" and "._MyFile" are two parts of the *same* file, and it doesn't normally return two directory entries for one file.)  You only see these companion files on non-HFS disks that you move to other operating systems.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2006/Jun/msg00180.html

So, the only Options I see is using VCP7, or Paralles, etc., to have a pseodo way to see them in Finder, or....

Write a script to list those files in a window & maybe link them back the the real ._ files.

Comment: In my case, '._Folder' is a real folder. It's just named that way, but that link you've provided explains a lot as to why the OS wouldn't want to show files with that naming convention. Thanks. I think I might make the case to rename the folder to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find an answer in their support section, but you might give the 30-day trial of Path Finder a try and see if it lets you see the ._ files.

http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/